# jQuery closest to find submenu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here, why jQuery `closest` isn't working ? I've tried using `find`, `next` but doesn't work. I want to add `html` only in closest `class` of `li` which contains `children` `ul`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('li').children("ul").length) {
    $(this).closest(".submenu").html('+');
  }
})
```

```css
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
ul li{
  list-style:none;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
}

ul li ul li{
 float:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>General<span class="submenu"></span></li>
    <li>Extra<span class="submenu"></span></li>
    <li>Sport<span class="submenu"></span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Volleyball
        </li>
        <li>
          Football
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong

Comment: shouldn't it be `$(this).find("span.submenu").html('+');` instead of `$(this).closest(".submenu").html('+');`

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti, doesn't work

Comment: `closest` is the "closest" parent.  

ie go up from `this` until you find a matching node .  `$(this).closest() == $(this).parent()`  

It's useful when eg you want to find the containing table cell or a wrapper div eg `$("this).closest("td")` and `this` is somewhere inside that `td` but you don't know/care where.

In your code `this` is the document, which is the highest level and doesn't have a parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the length of `ul` which is inside the `li`.

```js
$('.submenu').parent().each(function(){
    if ($(this).children("ul").length) {
      $(this).find('.submenu').html('+');
    }
})
```

```css
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
ul li{
  list-style:none;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
}

ul li ul li{
 float:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
  <li>General<span class="submenu"></span></li>
  <li>Extra<span class="submenu"></span></li>
  <li>Sport<span class="submenu"></span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Volleyball
      </li>
      <li>
        Football
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the easiest way by changing the code from

```
if ($('li').children("ul").length) {
    $(this).find('span').html('+');
  }
```

to this

```
  $('ul li:has(ul)').find(".submenu").html('+');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul li:has(ul)').find(".submenu").html('+');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <ul>
    <li>General<span class="submenu"></span></li>
    <li>Extra<span class="submenu"></span></li>
    <li>Sport<span class="submenu"></span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Volleyball
        </li>
        <li>
          Football
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```